# seq2seq - Encoder backpropagation

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, lstm, backpropagation, encoder

I have a trouble understanding how back-propagation works in Encoder in seq2seq model. There are no labels, therefore it's not possible to calculate error, which is back-propagated, however weights of LSTM layer are somehow updated.

```
l_enc_input = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, None, embedding_size))
l_enc_lstm = LSTM(encoding_size, return_sequences=False, return_state=True, stateful=True, dropout=0.2)

l_dec_input = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, None, embedding_size))
l_dec_lstm = LSTM(encoding_size, return_sequences=False, stateful=True, dropout=0.2)
l_dec_dense = Dense(embedding_size, activation="softmax")


t_enc_out = l_enc_lstm(l_enc_input)
state = t_enc_out[1:]

t_dec_out = l_dec_dense(l_dec_lstm(l_dec_input, initial_state=state))

model_train = Model(inputs=[l_enc_input, l_dec_input], outputs=[t_dec_out])
model_train.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy")
```

Answer (score 0):

A seq2seq/autoencoder consists of an **encoder** that processes the input and a **decoder** that generates the output. During training, input is provided to the encoder and the output of the encoder is provided to the decoder. The goal is that the output of the decoder should be close to the input. So this is how the loss is computed, between the output of the decoder and the input.

In high level pseudo-code:

Let `x` be the input.

```
x' = decoder(encoder(x))
loss = f(x', x)
```

Hope that helps!

There is a great explanation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq).
Also the wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder) is very detailed.

Comment: In the code, **output** of the encoder **is not provided** to the decoder. Only **internal state** of encoders LSTM is set as initial state of decoders LSTM. This is why I'm confused, how weights of the encoder are updated.